# How to open a c project in source insight?

Tags: editor, c

Someone recommends me to use **SI**  to read the c source of PHP ,a great open source project.

I've already downloaded the source.

But I don't know how to import it,can anyone help?

Comment: if you just need to open a c source file, you can look at bloodshed dev c++, its what I use: http://www.bloodshed.net/download.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't, but it does a lot as far as C/C++ IDEs go.

Comment: @MaQleod: I hope that recommending DevC++ was a joke.

Comment: SourceInsight is not an IDE, it's a tool to understand source code...it's more of a source code browser. And Dev-C++ is indeed horrible, but others have already written that down, so we don't have to: http://www.jasonbadams.net/20081218/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/

Answer (score 3):

Open the Project menu and create a new project (or push Alt+Shift+N). In the upcoming dialog window, enter PHP as the project's name and select a folder to store the project data. Click OK to configure the project, e.g. activate storing function-local symbols in the project DB etc. Click OK again.

The next dialog lets you actually import files to the project. Select your source folder and click "Add Tree" to add the whole directory structure to the project. Click Close. You can now start browsing the source code.

Make sure you configure SourceInsight so that it knows where your local library folders are, i.e. the C headers & runtime. This is usually done when installing SourceInsight.